# How WordPress can list users with specific capabilities

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to list only the users that has a specific capability, such us "publish_posts" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list users with [WP_User_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query), but afaik you can only return different roles, not permissions, maybe that's already what you want! There's also a site where you can see the different [roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) in the wordpress documentation.

Comment: I already knew about roles and capabilities ;) Thanks. The help I was need was about how to list the authors ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: In WordPress 4.1+ you can use the 'role' search parameter to search for capabilities.

For example:
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'publish_posts' )  );

However, the user has to have the capability added to them (e.g. they cannot 'inherit' the capability from a role).  So this won't work for many needs, but will for specific ones.

(For example, I have a capability of 'staff' which is not added to any roles, but granted on a per-user basis)

Answer (score 13):

To select users with certain capabilities you can use WP_User_Query with meta_query parameter,  because WP stores capabilities as a serialized string in user_meta table.
Also remember that due to availability to have multisite installation capabilities name in user meta looks like wp_table_prefix_capabilities.

```
global $wpdb;
// meta-key name
$capabilities_field_name=$wpdb->prefix.'capabilities';
//array as argument for our query
$qargs=[
     'role' => ['Customer'], // use this if you need to query by role at the same time
     'meta_query'=>
         [
            'relation' => 'OR', // optional if you'll need to select more than
                                //  one capability just add this and create same array
                               // as down below describing what are you looking for 
             [
                'key' => $capabilities_field_name,
                'value' => 'your_role_name',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
             ],

       // here could be same array [key,value,compare]... as above with another capability      
       // but you'll need to add extra argument showing relationship between them see above 'relation parameter'

         ],
     'number'=> -1 // to select all users
 ];

$usersQuery=new WP_User_Query($qargs); // instantiate UserQuery with $qargs

$users=$usersQuery->get_results(); // get all results as array of WPUser objects
```

Hope it helps somebody:)
Note [vars] could be substituted to array(vars), I like [] short syntax but it's supported only since php 5.4.

Comment: @DominikSpäte Thank you for your reply . i've added number-1 and fixed $ in code sample.

Comment: Just letting others know - this answer is absolutely superior to other one. Tested and it works much smoother than querying through a whole user database. I definitely recommend this solution especially if you have many users.

Answer (score 10):

You can just retrieve all users. Then loop through them in a foreach. Check if the user has a specific capability then push the users to another array and use that array to list them.

```
$all_users = get_users();
$specific_users = array();

foreach($all_users as $user){

    if($user->has_cap('specific_capability')){
        $specific_users[] = $user;
    }

}
```

**NOTE:**
It seemed a nice quick and dirty solution at the time, but now I would recommend writing a query. I do not have the time to investigate this for you, so if the one downvoting this would be so kind to answer this question instead of downvoting an answer which was an actual help to the inquirer, that would be nice.

Comment: I know it's an old question and you were already helped out, but I thought people who are looking to list users on a capability might find this useful.

Comment: hmm. So If there are say 5 thousand users on site. one will have to loop through 5000 records and for each user check whether the user has the SPECIFIC CAPABILITY?

Comment: I agree it's neither ideal or scalable for larger user bases. It would be better to let the filtering take place with SQL. However at the time I thought is was a nice quick fix. I invite you to answer the question with the proper query. If you don't / can't / won't, I will sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to get all the roles that contain that capability. Then you can search users based on the roles that contain that capability.

```
$roles = array();
foreach ( wp_roles()->roles as $role_name => $role_obj ) {
    if ( ! empty( $role_obj['capabilities']['my_capability_name'] ) ) {
        $roles[] = $role_name;
    }
}

$users = get_users( array( 'role__in' => $roles ) );
```

- This does not account for if another role has "Deny" on that capability and your users can contain multiple roles. If so then you will also need to add a "user_can()" condition when looping through your Users. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_can/