# custom query to get user id from wordpress usermeta key and value

Tags: wordpress

I need a custom query to get all the user except Administrator wp_capabilities != "Administrator"

select id from wp_users, wp_usermeta where meta_key="wp_capabilities".....not sure

the wp_capabilities has some value like a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;} user and a:2:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;s:13:"bbp_keymaster";b:1;} for administrator.

Any help would highly appreciated.

Comment: You could do things like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18528323/1720332)  if that suits your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List **all** users:

```
$users = get_users();
```

Filter for **role** (ex. subscriber):

```
$users = get_users('role=subscriber');
```

Exclude for **id** user:

```
$users = get_users('exclude=1');
```

Filter for **roles** (ex. all except the administrators):

```
function get_users() { 

$users = array();
$roles = array('subscriber', 'contributor', 'author', 'editor');

foreach ($roles as $role) :
    $users_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
        'fields' => 'all_with_meta', 
        'role' => $role, 
        'orderby' => 'display_name'
        ) );
    $results = $users_query->get_results();
    if ($results) $users = array_merge($users, $results);
endforeach;

return $users;
```

}